# Bash-script. Shift seconds

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, date

In bash I don't know how to do that. I need to do a bash-script. At stdin I have .srt file of subtitles in this format:

```
num
HH:MM:SS,SSS --> HH:MM:SS,SSS
text line 1
text line 2
...
```

HH:MM:SS,SSS start and finish of title for text.

Script must shift seconds. (it can be + or -)

Example:

```
$cat bmt.srt
5
00:01:02,323 --> 00:01:05,572
Hello, my frieds!
6
....

$./shifter.sh +3<mbt.srt
5
00:01:05,323 --> 00:01:08,572
Hello, my frieds!
6
```

I need to grab all HH:MM:SS and convert them to seconds firstly. Is somebody able do this without sed?

Comment: mplayer has some subtitle delay options, only I don't know if it can store it as new subtitle; still, I suspect there's an existing solution for this out there somewhere...

Answer (score 7):

Unless the subtitle file spans more than 24 hours, you can use `date` for this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o errexit -o noclobber -o nounset -o pipefail

date_offset="$1"

shift_date() {
    date --date="$1 $date_offset" +%T,%N | cut -c 1-12
}

while read -r line
do
    if [[ $line =~ ^[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9]\ --\>\ [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9]$ ]]
    then
        read -r start_date separator end_date <<<"$line"
        new_start_date="$(shift_date "$start_date")"
        new_end_date="$(shift_date "$end_date")"
        printf "%s %s %s\n" "$new_start_date" "$separator" "$new_end_date"
        echo "New date"
    else
        printf "%s\n" "$line"
    fi
done
```

For some reason you need to use decimal numbers with this, but it works:

```
$ ./shifter.sh "+3.0 seconds" < bmt.srt
5
00:01:05,323 --> 00:01:08,572
New date
Hello, my frieds!
6
```

Answer (score 5):

Perl solution. I did not use any classical time handling module, as miliseconds handling is generally poorly supported.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use constant FACTORS => (60 * 60 * 1000,
                              60 * 1000,
                                   1000,
                                      1);

sub time2ms {
    my $time = shift;
    my ($ms, $i) = (0, 0);
    $ms += (FACTORS)[$i++] * $_ for split /[^0-9]/, $time;
    return $ms;
}


sub ms2time {
    my $ms = shift;
    my $str = q();
    for my $i (0 .. 3) {
                $str .= sprintf +($i == 3 ? '%03d' : '%02d')
                                    . (':', ':', ',', q())[$i],
                                $ms / (FACTORS)[$i];
        $ms = $ms % (FACTORS)[$i];
    }
    return $str;
}


my $diff   = 1000 * shift;
my $TIME_R = qr/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3}/;
while (<>) {
    if (my ($from, $to) = /($TIME_R) --> ($TIME_R)/) {
        my $i = 0;
        for my $time ($from, $to) {
            $time = time2ms($time) + $diff;
            print ms2time($time), (' --> ', "\n")[$i++];
        }
    } else {
        print;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the script! Let me add a small improvement though: In the ms2time loop, if $i==3, sprintf should be '%03d' instead of '%02d'.

Comment: @VangelisTasoulas: Updated.